# AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'render'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

anyone know why this error is happening? i've been running the same line for my other tests and only this one is returning an error
both lines in test_coverageReturnSuccess + test_coverageReturnCorrectCoverage returning this error:

```
    response.render()
AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'render'
```

This is my APi test case

```
class CoverageTest(APITestCase):
    protein = None
    domain = None
    protein_domain = None
    good_url = ''
    bad_url = ''

    def setUp(self):
        self.protein = ProteinFactory.create(pk=1, protein_id='A0A014PQC0', length=338)
        self.domain = PfamFactory.create()
        self.protein_domain = ProteinDomainLinkFactory.create(protein=self.protein, 
                                                            pfam_id=self.domain, 
                                                            start=157, 
                                                            stop=314)
        # Set urls
        self.good_url = reverse('coverage', kwargs={'protein_id': 'A0A014PQC0'})


    def tearDown(self):
        # Reset test tables
        Protein.objects.all().delete()
        Pfam.objects.all().delete()
        ProteinDomainLink.objects.all().delete()
        # Reset primary keys
        ProteinFactory.reset_sequence(0)
        PfamFactory.reset_sequence(0)
        ProteinDomainLinkFactory.reset_sequence(0)


    def test_coverageReturnSuccess(self):
        """
        Ensure we get an 200 OK status code when making a valid GET request.
        """
        response = self.client.get(self.good_url, format='json')
        response.render()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_coverageReturnCorrectCoverage(self):
        """
        Ensure we get the right coverage of the requested protein
        """
        response = self.client.get(self.good_url, format='json')
        response.render()
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(data, 0.46449704142011833)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not *render* the response, the `response` is already rendered, so for example:

```
def test_coverageReturnSuccess(self):
    """
    Ensure we get an 200 OK status code when making a valid GET request.
    """
    response = self.client.get(self.good_url, format='json')
    # not response.render()!
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

For JSON, you use:

```
def test_coverageReturnCorrectCoverage(self):
    """
    Ensure we get the right coverage of the requested protein
    """
    response = self.client.get(self.good_url, format='json')
    # not response.render()!
    data = response.json()
    self.assertEqual(data, 0.46449704142011833)
```

Comment: i get this error when i remove response.render - json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - highlights: data = json.loads(response.content)

Comment: @akira: you use `response.json()` for that. But using a number as "outer" object is *not* a good idea!